# Leave no trailing comma at the end of the result if there's only one value at the end to be concatenated

Tags: excel, vba, text, concatenation

My current code takes selected columns and concatenates them dividing each value with a comma, inserting a column to the right of the sheet. However whenever there's a row where there's only one value it keeps leaving a trailing comma at the end. It doesn't leave a comma at the end of the result if there are multiple values, only when there's one, like for example:

multiple values: "text1,text2,text3"
single value: "text1,"

What I need: "text1"

Code:

```
    Sub ConcatenateSelectedRanges()
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim concatenatedString As String
    Dim resultColumn As Range
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Dim area As Range
    Dim isDateResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    ' Check if a range is selected
    On Error Resume Next
    Set selectedRange = Selection
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If selectedRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please select a range to concatenate.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Prompt the user if the content in the selected range is a date
    isDateResponse = MsgBox("Is the content in the selected range a date?" & vbCrLf & _
                            "Selected Range: " & selectedRange.Address, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Date Check")
    
    If isDateResponse = vbCancel Then
        Exit Sub ' Exit if the user cancels the prompt
    End If
    
    ' Find the first available empty column to the right of the selected range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set resultColumn = selectedRange.Offset(0, selectedRange.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If resultColumn Is Nothing Then
        ' If no available empty column is found, insert a new column at the end
        lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set resultColumn = Columns(lastColumn + 1).EntireColumn
        resultColumn.Insert
        ' Resize the resultColumn to match the height of the selected range
        Set resultColumn = resultColumn.Resize(selectedRange.Rows.Count)
    End If
    
    ' Loop through each area within the selection
    For Each area In selectedRange.Areas
        ' Loop through each row in the current area
        For rowIndex = 1 To area.Rows.Count
            ' Reset the concatenated string for each row
            concatenatedString = ""
            
            ' Loop through each cell in the current row
            For Each cell In area.Rows(rowIndex).Cells
                If cell.Value <> "" Then ' Ignore blank cells
                    If isDateResponse = vbYes Then
                        ' Append the formatted date to the string
                        concatenatedString = concatenatedString & Format(cell.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & ","
                    Else
                        ' Append the cell value to the string
                        concatenatedString = concatenatedString & cell.Value & ","
                    End If
                End If
            Next cell
            
            ' Remove the trailing comma if there's only one non-empty cell
            If Len(concatenatedString) > 0 Then
                If Len(concatenatedString) > 1 Then ' Check if there's more than one character
                    If Right(concatenatedString, 1) = "," Then
                        concatenatedString = Left(concatenatedString, Len(concatenatedString) - 1)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            
            ' Display the concatenated string in the corresponding row of the new column
            resultColumn.Cells(rowIndex + area.Rows(1).Row - 1, 1).Value = _
                resultColumn.Cells(rowIndex + area.Rows(1).Row - 1, 1).Value & IIf(resultColumn.Cells(rowIndex + area.Rows(1).Row - 1, 1).Value = "", "", ",") & concatenatedString
        Next rowIndex
    Next area
End Sub
```

Comment: test if the last character is a comma and remove it if true.

Comment: Alternatively, use an array to collect the values (`redim preserve` on each iteration to grow it and add the new item) then `join` the array to get your concatenated list.

Comment: I need the comma to separate the values, just not at the end of the result. If it's only one value in the end it should have no comma.

Comment: You can follow the pattern I used in my answer to your previous question.  Use a separate variable for the comma and only populate it once the first item has been added.

Comment: Will the selected range have non-contiguous columns ie A:B and D ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the result string consists of text followed by the comma as per this code

```
                        concatenatedString = concatenatedString & Format(cell.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & ","
                    Else
                        ' Append the cell value to the string
                        concatenatedString = concatenatedString & cell.Value & ","
```

you only need to check the length of the string is greater than zero and remove the trailing comma!

```
            ' Remove the trailing comma if there's only one non-empty cell
            If Len(concatenatedString) > 0 Then
                        concatenatedString = Left(concatenatedString, Len(concatenatedString) - 1)
            End If
```

Take it easy!

**The root cause of the trail comma is in this line:**

```
            resultColumn.Cells(rowIndex + area.Rows(1).Row - 1, 1).Value = _
                resultColumn.Cells(rowIndex + area.Rows(1).Row - 1, 1).Value & IIf(resultColumn.Cells(rowIndex + area.Rows(1).Row - 1, 1).Value = "", "", ",") & concatenatedString
```

I don't want to dive into it. Just apply the additional check:

```
            resultColumn.Cells(rowIndex + area.Row - 1, 1) = _
                resultColumn.Cells(rowIndex + area.Row - 1, 1) _
                & IIf(resultColumn.Cells(rowIndex + area.Row - 1, 1) = "" Or Len(concatenatedString) = 0, "", ",") _
                & concatenatedString
```

Comment: I replaced it with yours and it keeps working with some but not with others :(

https://imgur.com/jvcxXdC

Maybe it's an issue in one of the loops? Just can't put my finger on it. Don't know if it has anything to do with the last character being a letter or a number.

Comment: Added the solution.

Comment: I just double checked this and it stops adding the data from the second column to the concatenated result at the 31st row. It just adds the first column.

Comment: :-) It's not your question...

Comment: To debug your code, put "Debug.Print area.Rows.Count" into next line after "For rowIndex = 1 To area.Rows.Count", run your code then check the result in the Immediate window (VB editor, Ctrl+G). Compare your expectation against the real number of processed rows.